# How do i use Subprocess.popen() with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, exe, pyinstaller

I have a bunch of code and one of the lines is this (in abc.py):

`meow = subprocess.Popen("python ./Functions/cat.py")`

Now when i use `pyinstaller.exe --onefile .\abc.py`

It makes me a single exe and it implements all the function but the function containing above line does not work.

How do i include cat.py in exe and use it with subprocess.popen?

My folder view is

> ```
>     -Project x
>              -abc.py
>              -Functions
>                       -cat.py
>                       -me.py
>                       -ow.py
> ```

Cat.py has a function which listens for input and runs forever till i have to stop it based on certain input.

I am running abc.py and based on certain input i have to run cat.py along with abc.py and on some another input i have to stop cat.py(using .kill()) and abc.py will still be running.

How do i implement this in a single exe using pyinstaller?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out in the end?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to handle this issue.  I believe if you called cat.py with an import statement, it would package just fine.  The other option is to create a .spec file, 
and then package cat.py as a data file ([or the entire function folder using the Tree class](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/advanced-topics.html#the-toc-and-tree-classes)).  If you package it as a data file, check out [this post for coding to call it while developing as well as once its packaged by --onefile.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile)